# logstash monitor spark-on-yarn application logs

Tags: apache-spark, logstash, logstash-configuration

I installed a logstash on my spark node.

The problem is it can't collect all logs from the dynamic created containers' folders. It does collect part of the logs, which is from only one of the container. Here is the input part of my logstash config file:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/userXXX/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/userlogs/application_*/container_*/*"
  }
```

So the question is, does the path with `*` cover all the container folders, including those will be created at runtime?

Comment: For those finding this in 2018+, please use FileBeat. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/migrating-from-logstash-forwarder.html